# Javascript: Need help to display a variable in a textbox

Tags: javascript

Upon the click of a button I need to display the appropriate variable to a specific text-box. I've set the variables up in an array so when the user clicks the "Input" button a prompt will appear and ask four questions (1 per each column).

I've attempted to display each prompt with a text box. That's where my problem occurs. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonMsg() {
    varData = new Array()

    varData[0] = prompt("Please enter first name.","")
    varData[1] = prompt("Please enter last name.","")
    varData[2] = prompt("Please enter phone number.","")
    varData[3] = prompt("Please enter address.","")
}
</script>
<body>
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>0,0 CustomerID</td>
    <td>1 FirstName </td>
    <td>2 LastName </td>
    <td>3 Phone </td>
    <td>4 Address </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>        
    <td>1 Customer1 <input type="button" value="Input" onclick="buttonMsg()" />    </td>       
    <td><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="varData[1]"></td>
    <td><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="varData[1]"></td>
    <td><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="varData[2]"></td>
    <td><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="varData[3]"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>        
    <td>2 Customer2 </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3 Customer3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4 Customer4 </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use `;` on the end of your statements: `varData = new Array();`, note the `;` at the end of the line. Each statement should have semicolons (and yes, I *know* Javascript lets you get away with it, but it's a bad habit to get into and may cause unforeseen problems). Also, you `<script>` block belongs within the `<head>`, as does the `<title>` block.

Comment: Demo of code as posted in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/WELc8/

Comment: @JaredFarrish SCRIPT elements don't belong in the HEAD. As a matter of fact, it's a good idea to place them at the bottom of the page: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Show me something that says they *do not belong* in a `HEAD` tag, other than the "best practice" preached by the Yahoo team. Not to mention the point was they need to be in a tag other than the `HTML` tag. `;)` To wit: [*This element may appear any number of times in the HEAD or BODY of an HTML document.*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT).

Comment: @Jared `:)` Ah yes, I phrased it badly. I meant it's not true that a SCRIPT element (exclusively) belongs in the HEAD, as it can also appear inside the BODY.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - I wasn't trying to imply that either, what I figured was that the OP meant to put it in the `<head>` due to where it was located. I see what you mean, and I didn't exactly phrase it that well either.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I see what you meant. The HEAD element is prematurely closed.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Funny how plaintext can lead to misunderstandings and misinterpretations so easily... No worries. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function buttonMsg(){
   varData = new Array()

   varData[0] = prompt("Please enter first name.","")
   varData[1] = prompt("Please enter last name.","")
   varData[2] = prompt("Please enter phone number.","")
   varData[3] = prompt("Please enter address.","")

   document.getElementsByName('inputbox')[0].value = varData[0];
   document.getElementsByName('inputbox')[1].value = varData[1];
   document.getElementsByName('inputbox')[2].value = varData[2];
   document.getElementsByName('inputbox')[3].value = varData[3];
}
```

Comment: `var varData = [];` instead of `varData = new Array()`

Comment: Also cache the query: `var boxes =  document.getElementsByName('inputbox');` and then `boxes[0] = ... ; boxes[1] = ...;` There's no need to run the query four times.

Comment: ye, you are all right, but we are dealing with a beginner so i wrote it this way to make it easy to understand. I could also have used a for loop to populate the inputs...

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WELc8/1/ I added `;` and rearranged some stuff, including taking into account @ŠimeVidas's comment above.

Comment: Andre's answer worked but now I have run into a new problem. How can I make more than one array each initiated by a separate button? I tried but it doesn't display anything now.

Comment: I tried function buttonMsg(1) for my second button but apparently that didn't work